# Ensure unique Username / Emails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am currently using Asp MVC / Identity 2.0 to build a membership site.
I have made some changes that now allow a user todo the following :

- Create separate username / email values on account creation
- Login using either username or email through a single text field

What I am concerned about is should user Alice register an account as follows :

Username - Alice

Email - alice@example.com

*User Bob could create an account as follows :*

Username - alice@example.com

Email - evilbob@l33th4x0rs.com

I'd like to ensure, that should a user create an account, their username is unique in both the UserName and EmailAddress columns.

I have currently achieved within my RegisterViewModel as follows

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9 \.\&\'\-]+)$", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be alpha numeric")]                 
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

As such it is not possible to enter an email into the username field - is this the best way to do this though?

I'm concerned that later down the line, I may want to allow some special characters in the username field.

Forgive me if this is a n00b question, I'm still very much new to this.

Comment: As a side note, I'm aware that whilst the username - email would be identical in the above example, from a security perspective the accounts would be seperate, however the potential for someone to be fooled whilst using the app does not sit well with me

Comment: Is there a reason you have username and email as separate fields, if you want to enforce uniqueness across them?

Comment: By far the easiest way to do this would be to make the username be the email address and just add a unique constraint on the email address in the database.  The next best would be to create a check constraint in the database.  (doing this in code will not ensure the records don't get created in the database.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ensure uniqueness of your records using the Data annotations you have in your view model properties. Those are for helping validations & display purposes primarily.

What you should be doing is checking the userName value againist both `UserName` and `Email` field of your User table and allow/deny user to continue his action.

To check the userName against both email and userName fields , you might try something like this.

```
var userNameToCheck="alice@ss.com";
var exists=db.Users.Any(x=>x.UserName==userNameToCheck||x.Email==userNameToCheck);
if(!exists)
{
  // New record. Let's continue saving it.
}
```

But a better solution is to use email as your username for the app(Only one column in db table) and keep a unique constraint on that column(Email) to prevent accidental duplicate entry even if your code failed to stop the duplicate entry insertion.

You should always have validation in your code and db (constraints) to be on the safer side.

Comment: You better enforce this in the database as well, because that code contains a race condition.

Comment: What is the race condition ?

Comment: Do you really have 68k+ reputation and really just asked what a race condition is? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: My question is what is the race condition of the above code ? The answer was meant to give an idea about suggesting a better approach than the data annotations.

Comment: Ahh... okay.  without the check in the database it is possible to run this code and create two duplicate users at the same time.  (heck, it is possible to run this code at two difference times and have the second one pass if the first record is locked.)